# Sentence grammar usage "as"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

> He was exposed as lacking in intelligence.

I'm writing this sentence but I feel there is something amiss with the grammar, but I can't tell exactly why or where. Something to do with "as" I suspect.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: _As_ is a bit problematic, like most small words. Normally it can be thought to be a bastard form of _be_, and indeed normally you can substitute some other form of _be_, -- _exposed to be lacking, exposed as being lacking,_ etc. But some constructions require it, and it can appear in equative constructions like _as pretty as a picture_ with no meaning except equative.

Comment: I think it's fine. *Lacking in intelligence* is a gerund phrase here, and it functions like a noun does. You can swap in another noun phrase to test: *He was exposed as an idiot.*

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct as far as I can see. Depending on the context, we could come up with less ambiguous sentences that share the same meaning.